# How to loop through a taxonomy vocabulary to find the top category in a nested tree?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, database

What I have so far is this

```
$term=therm_id_that_I_already_have;

$parent = db_result(db_query("SELECT h.parent FROM {term_data} d INNER JOIN {term_hierarchy} h ON d.tid = h.tid WHERE d.tid = $term"));
$term = $parent;


$th=taxonomy_get_term($term);
```

probably I need a while of something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using [taxonomy_get_parents_all().](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_parents_all/7) If you have a vocabylary that looks like:

- Vocabulary

  - Child 1 (tid=1)

    - Child 1.1 (tid=3)
  - Child 2 (tid=2)

Then you can do:

```
<?php
$parents = taxonomy_get_parents_all(3);
$top_category = array_pop($parents);
```

Will give you the term for tid 1.